# What to do to enable SSH service on CentOS hosted in local Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, nat

I googled a lot but didn't help. So, I have another PC in my local network that has Windows Server 2012 R2. I enabled Hyper-V and initiated CentOS 7.2 and configured SSH server. The thing is I want to be able to connect to CentOS through my local network. Disregarding every guides resides in web, what steps should I take to accomplish that? I already tried creating an Internal Switch in Hyper-V and used the command below but didn't help:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 connectaddress=192.168.0.100 connectport=8080 protocol=tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

Internal Switch will only allow communication between VM and Host, but will NOT allow external, in your case LAN, communication.

Try changing switch to external and see if you're able to get in to CentOS.

Comment: I already have an External switch turned on. :/

Comment: Can you post screenshots of VM network settings, host switch settings and IPs of your guest and host machines?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a "netsh" command string listed up there.  Netsh is a Windows tool.  So that makes me think that you're very confused about how virtual machines work.  If you've connected your CentOS VM to an external virtual switch (one with a physical NIC) then any configuration you'll need to make will be done within CentOS, not Windows.  Look for the right CentOS tool, not a Windows tool.